# key function for heapq.nlargest()

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, heap, python-collections

I have a dictionary with `{key: count}`, say
`status_count = {'MANAGEMENT ANALYSTS': 13859, 'COMPUTER PROGRAMMERS': 72112}`
and I am trying to write a key function for heapq.nlargest() that sorts based on count and if there are ties I have to sort based on alphabetical order(a-z) of keys. I have to use heapq.nlargest because of very large N and small k = 10.

This is what I got until now,

`top_k_results = heapq.nlargest(args.top_k, status_count.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]))`

But, this would be incorrect in case of breaking ties with alphabetical order. Please help!

Comment: Can you show a sample of the dictionary you are working on?

Comment: @Austin I just updated the question with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest may be to switch to `heapq.nsmallest` and redefine your sort key:

```
from heapq import nsmallest

def sort_key(x):
    return -x[1], x[0]

top_k_results = nsmallest(args.top_k, status_count.items(), key=sort_key)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and take the negative for ascending order:

```
from heapq import nlargest

def sort_key(x):
    return x[1], [-ord(i) for i in x[0]]

top_k_results = nlargest(args.top_k, status_count.items(), key=sort_key)
```

Remember to use [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) if you need to normalize the case of your string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have strings with length > 1 and `ord()` would accept only strings of length 1 I guess. Is there a way to overcome this?